# Generating a new random canvas point for a snake game

Tags: javascript

Im making a snake game in vanilla JS, the "apple" is being drawn randomly on the game board but needs to be re-drawn when the snake hits the apple. I do get "hit apple" in the console but the apple does not get re-drawn.

```
let apple = [
    {
        x: Math.floor(Math.random() * (600 / 10)) * 10,
        y: Math.floor(Math.random() * (600 / 10)) * 10
    }
];
function drawApple() {
    apple.forEach(applePart);
    if (snakeBody[0].x === apple[0].x && snakeBody[0].y === apple[0].y) {
        newApple();
        console.log('hit apple')
    }
};

function newApple() {
    apple.x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (600 / 10)) * 10
    apple.y = Math.floor(Math.random() * (600 / 10)) * 10
}

function applePart() {
    canvasContext.fillStyle = 'green';
    canvasContext.strokeStyle = 'white'
    canvasContext.fillRect(apple[0].x, apple[0].y, 10, 10);
    canvasContext.strokeRect(apple[0].x, apple[0].y, 10, 10);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to supply an anonymous function to forEach.

```
apple.forEach(function(element){
  applePart()
});
```

I don't get why you are using forEach when you only have one apple (I think your idea is to add more). Note : element is one of the elements of the array being used.

Answer (score 0):

Your `newApple` function points the **array** `apple`, instead of the actual **element**, `apple[0]`.

It's a good indication that a singular noun isn't a good name for an array. The plural form, `apples`, is a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

Put a slightly different way from TheOwl: your `newapple` function is inconsistent with the rest of your code. Given that you've defined apple as an *array*, you need to index into the array to get specific elements, but this code:

```
function newApple() {
    apple.x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (600 / 10)) * 10
    apple.y = Math.floor(Math.random() * (600 / 10)) * 10
}
```

will try to modify the `x` and `y` properties of the array itself, not its zero'th element — and this 'turns it into' an object. If you want to keep your apples as an array, then either `newApple()` needs to specify itself to `apple[0].x` and `apple[0].y`; if you go this route, though, you should be iterating over *all* the elements of the array whenever you access `apple[0]`. What the semantics of that should be (i.e., how you want to look at all the elements) is more a question of design than code.